# flatmap need additional loader

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, flatten

I have this array of objects in a js file and I have imported the js file to the vue file.

food.js

```
food = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "burger",
    ingredients: [
       {
         name: "tomato",
         amount: "2 pcs"
       },
       {
         name: "meat",
         amount: "2 pcs"
       }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "ice cream",
    ingredients: [
       {
         name: "milk",
         amount: "xxxx"
       },
       {
         name: "food coloring",
         amount: "xxxxx"
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

script

```
import { food } from '@/data/food'
export default { 
   components: {food},
   data() {
        return {
            ingredientsList: food.flatMap(q => q.ingredients)
        }
    },
}
```

I want to get all ingredients from all objects, but it shows this error

```
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     data() {
|         return {
>             ingredientsList: food.flatMap(q => q.ingredients)
|         }
|     },
```

Is my code wrong or do I really need additional loaders? What kind of loaders do I need? I've searched everywhere and I didn't find any answer. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `food.js`

check `name: burger` I think you missed the quote `"`, try `name: "bugger"`

add `export const food = [...` to:

```
export const food = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "burger",
    ingredients: [
       {
         name: "tomato",
         amount: "2 pcs"
       },
       {
         name: "meat",
         amount: "2 pcs"
       }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "ice cream",
    ingredients: [
       {
         name: "milk",
         amount: "xxxx"
       },
       {
         name: "food coloring",
         amount: "xxxxx"
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

in vue

```
import { food } from '@/data/food.js'
export default {
   data() {
        return {
            ingredientsList: food.flatMap(q => q.ingredients)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `food` array is inside the `data()` method in order to use it, or import it when it's in another file.

```js
data() {
  const food = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: burger,
      ingredients: [
         {
           name: "tomato",
           amount: "2 pcs"
         },
         {
           name: "meat",
           amount: "2 pcs"
         }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "ice cream",
      ingredients: [
         {
           name: "milk",
           amount: "xxxx"
         },
         {
           name: "food coloring",
           amount: "xxxxx"
         }
      ]
    }
  ];

  return {
    ingredientsList: food.flatMap(q => q.ingredients);
  }
}
```

Comment: ah sorry i forgot to mention. the food array is already imported from another js file..